# What are the style parameters for nested lists?

Tags: lists, indentation, memoir, nesting

I am working in memoir class and would like to customize some nested lists. But I do not know all the style parameters, in particular, the lengths. How can I list them? This is a generic question, but I provide the following example. To what length does \leftmargin refer outside the lists, within the outer list, and within the inner list?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}
\begin{document}
$\backslash$leftmargin = \the\leftmargin
\begin{description}
  \item{Outer 1} $\backslash$leftmargin = \the\leftmargin
  \begin{description}
    \item{Inner 1} $\backslash$leftmargin = \the\leftmargin
    \item{Inner 2} $\backslash$leftmargin = \the\leftmargin
  \end{description}
\item{Outer 2} $\backslash$leftmargin = \the\leftmargin
\end{description}
$\backslash$leftmargin = \the\leftmargin
\end{document}

Output
\leftmargin = 29.3747pt
 Outer 1 \leftmargin = 29.3747pt
 Inner 1 \leftmargin = 25.84969pt
 Inner 2 \leftmargin = 25.84969pt
 Outer 2 \leftmargin = 29.3747pt
\leftmargin = 29.3747pt
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. Right now, it is not really clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: LaTeX and the `memoir` document class feature quite a few list-like environments. Which ones are you particularly interested in customizing?

Comment: @cfr & Mico.  Thank you for you replies. I have modified the question. What I really want is to know are names of the various style parameters like \leftmargin, \listparindent, etc. and whether each list has its own set that can be modified outside the lists.

Comment: By the way, in text mode, it's better to write `\textbackslash` than `$\backslash$`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relevant code in `memoir.cls` is from line 4572 to line 4607:

```
\def\@listi{\leftmargin\leftmargini
  \parsep\parsepi
  \topsep\topsepi
  \itemsep\itemsepi}
\let\@listI\@listi
\defaultlists
\@listi

\def\@listii{\leftmargin\leftmarginii
             \labelwidth\leftmarginii
             \advance\labelwidth-\labelsep
             \topsep\topsepii
             \parsep\parsepii
             \itemsep\parsepii}

\def\@listiii{\leftmargin\leftmarginiii
              \labelwidth\leftmarginiii
              \advance\labelwidth-\labelsep
              \topsep\topsepiii
              \parsep\z@
%%%              \itemsep\topsep
%%%              \partopsep \p@ \@plus\z@ \@minus\p@
              \itemsep\itemsepiii
              \partopsep\partopsepiii}

\def\@listiv{\leftmargin\leftmarginiv
             \labelwidth\leftmarginiv
             \advance\labelwidth-\labelsep}

\def\@listv{\leftmargin\leftmarginv
            \labelwidth\leftmarginv
            \advance\labelwidth-\labelsep}

\def\@listvi{\leftmargin\leftmarginvi
             \labelwidth\leftmarginvi
             \advance\labelwidth-\labelsep}
```

where we see that the lists are defined in terms of `\leftmarginX`, where `X` stands for the (lowercase) Roman numeral denoting the list nesting level.

In `mem12.clo` we find

```
\renewcommand{\normalsize}{%
   \@setfontsize\normalsize\@xiipt{14.5}%
   \abovedisplayskip 12\p@ \@plus3\p@ \@minus7\p@
   \abovedisplayshortskip \z@ \@plus3\p@
   \belowdisplayshortskip 6.5\p@ \@plus3.5\p@ \@minus3\p@
   \belowdisplayskip \abovedisplayskip
   \let\@listi\@listI}
\normalsize
\newcommand{\small}{%
   \@setfontsize\small\@xipt{13.6}%
   \abovedisplayskip 11\p@ \@plus3\p@ \@minus6\p@
   \abovedisplayshortskip \z@ \@plus3\p@
   \belowdisplayshortskip 6.5\p@ \@plus3.5\p@ \@minus3\p@
   \def\@listi{\leftmargin\leftmargini
               \topsep 9\p@ \@plus3\p@ \@minus5\p@
               \parsep 4.5\p@ \@plus2\p@ \@minus\p@
               \itemsep \parsep
%%               \itemindent\z@
              }%
   \belowdisplayskip \abovedisplayskip
}
\newcommand{\footnotesize}{%
   \@setfontsize\footnotesize\@xpt\@xiipt
   \abovedisplayskip 10\p@ \@plus2\p@ \@minus5\p@
   \abovedisplayshortskip \z@ \@plus3\p@
   \belowdisplayshortskip 6\p@ \@plus3\p@ \@minus3\p@
   \def\@listi{\leftmargin\leftmargini
               \topsep 6\p@ \@plus2\p@ \@minus2\p@
               \parsep 3\p@ \@plus2\p@ \@minus\p@
               \itemsep \parsep
%%               \itemindent\z@
              }%
   \belowdisplayskip \abovedisplayskip
}
```

where we see that first level lists are redefined in the sizes `\small` and `\footnotesize`, the only ones where a list should be typeset in.

The values of the parameters is established in lines 4406 to 4421 of `memoir.cls`

```
\if@twocolumn
  \setlength{\leftmargini}{2em}
\else
  \setlength{\leftmargini}{2.5em}
\fi
\leftmargin \leftmargini
\setlength{\leftmarginii}{2.2em}
\setlength{\leftmarginiii}{1.87em}
\setlength{\leftmarginiv}{1.7em}
\if@twocolumn
  \setlength{\leftmarginv}{.5em}
  \setlength{\leftmarginvi}{.5em}
\else
  \setlength{\leftmarginv}{1em}
  \setlength{\leftmarginvi}{1em}
\fi
```

This part of the code is processed *after* `memYY.clo` has been read in, so after `\normalsize` has been issued and, as a consequence, the value of `em` is taken from the main font *at that point*, which is Computer Modern.

If you want to modify them, you're free to do it; if you plan to use `em` units, then do the changes using `\AtBeginDocument` after the font package you like has been loaded.

As you see, there are several parameters: `\topsepX`, `\parsepX`, `\partopsepX` (for `X` equal to `i`, `ii or`iii`).

The `memoir` class sets them using `\defaultlists`, but there are also `\firmlists` and `\tightlists`, see the manual.

Comment: Wouldn't it just be easier to base lists on `enumitem`?

Comment: @egreg Thank you. This is what I was looking for.